# How to bind html to an rdlc file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, report, rdlc

I have text stored in a column of a table within my database, with html tags .

Example :

```
 <table><tr><td> hello </td></tr></table>
```

I am binding the text to the website and it works perfectly. It gets displayed as

```
   hello
```

on the website.

Now I would like to create a rdlc report and am binding the same dataset to the report.
But I see :

```
 <table><tr><td> hello </td></tr></table>
```

on the report instead of

```
hello
```

I think I understand why this is happenning , because the rdlc file cannot render html. But is there a way 
that I can see "hello" on the website. ? Please let me know if you know of any other way to do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can render using HTML tags in RDL as follows :

1. Left click the field you want to display so that the `<Expr>` tag is highlighted
2. Right click the highlighted `<Expr>` tag and choose `Placeholder Properties...`
3. On the `General` tab, select the `HTML- Interpret HTML tags as style` radio button

[image]

Comment: but it does not allow table tag and background color properties. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since RDLC Does not support table tag So you can apply the technique as follows:

1. Drag and drop Rectangle from Toolbox.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqLzl.png)
2. Drag and drop Text Box from Toolbox Label with column Name as like Table Header Row.
3. Drag and drop each Text Box from Toolbox Label with value as like table row.Iterate this drag and drop you want to create row.

Comment: dont use image or link of it in your asnwer